# Windows 10: enumerating sessionnames - access is denied

Tags: windows-10, permissions, task-manager

When I open Task Manager, Processes and Users tabs are empty. There are a lot of topic over the internet with the problem, but I couldn't find a fix for the problem.

Then tried to open a cmd prompt and type "quser", the result is:

```
C:\Windows\system32>quser
Error 0x00000005 enumerating sessionnames
Error [5]:Access is denied.
```

It's strange that a few hours after reboot everything is OK, but after some time this happens.

Comment: There should only be one user - You.  Do you really mean there are 0 processes in the Process Tab?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: `quser` is used to "[Display information about user sessions on a Terminal server or a Remote Desktop Session Host (RD Session Host) server.](https://ss64.com/nt/query-user.html)"

Comment: It's a laptop with only one local user. The command is executed in elevated cmd. Here is a screenshot of the [taskmanager](https://imgur.com/a/b1gcueb).
Unfortunately there are a lot of topics [like this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/task-manager-processes-tab-completely-blank/8d23de44-18a7-46f1-8f26-4cf5a12e7a36) where there isn't any actual solution. Updated the original post - bottom line

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any McAfee and/or RSA software on this system? I have found that this happens on my systems where RSA Authentication Client 3.6.0 is installed. If I open Task Manager, then go to the Details tab, I can end the "RsaCardUtility.exe" process that has the currently logged in user name. After ending the task, the quser error will go away and the Process and Users tab in Task Manager will return to normal without requiring a log out.

Comment: No, I don't have any antivirus software, but I have software for two vendors of digital signatures. I don't think they cause the problem, because this happened on days when I haven't sign any documents.
Recently I bought a MS Office Pro Plus then removed the old one and installed this and since then the problem happened only once after long uptime (2-3 weeks) with many sleep/hibernate sessions. I'm starting to think the old office was causing the problem.
But now the task manager closes much slower than before?!?... Strange things are happening...